# How to access a control in shared layout page from some other page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a new asp.net application. Till now, I have developed a layout view with navigation bar and footer, home page and a login page and it all works fine. Now after successful login I wish to change the login button in navigation bar to log out button. For that I have to access the layout view controls in login page but I can't. I've tried many solutions from Stack Overflow for this problem but unfortunately nothing worked for me.

As a first step, I've created a model class and a controller for the layout view so as to access the controls of layout view in some other page but I can't access the model property in the layout view itself.

**Layout Model:**

```
public class _LayoutModels
    {
        private string btnName = "Login";
        public string loginBtnName
        {
            get
            {
                return btnName;
            }
            set
            {
                btnName = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Layout Controller:**

```
public class _LayoutController : Controller
    {
        // GET: _Layout
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index(_LayoutModels lm)
        {
            lm.loginBtnName = "Login";  
            ViewData["Message"] = lm;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And if I try to use this property in layout view it throws null reference exception.

**Layout View code:**

```
@{ 
    var data = (_LayoutModels)ViewData["Message"];
}

@Html.ActionLink(@data.loginBtnName, "Index", "Login", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class = "nav-link" })
```

I hope I have explained my problem clearly. I want to access the controls in layout view so that I can change the name or functionality of it based on the login. If it is not possible to access the controls in layout view, then how can I do it? 
-Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you can use partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `session` to store login information. When you successfully log in save a key into a session variable like this,

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model){
    // your authentication and login
    Session["loggedUserId"] = userId; // loggedUserId is a key
}
```

now in your navigation html you can easily checks for login,

```
@{
    if(Session["loggedUserId"] !== null){
        // This block checks if user is logged in
        @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Login", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "logoutLink", @class = "nav-link" })
    }
    else {
        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Login", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class = "nav-link" })
    }
}
```

And do this in your logout method

```
public ActionResult Logout(){
    // Your logout logic
    Session["loggedUserId"] = null;
}
```

Comment: your solution solved my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

simply need to go your login button html and put it in if alse and check whether the user is authenticated or not and show button accordingly.see the code...

```html
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
   <li> <a href="@Url.Action("Method-Name", "Controoler-name", new { area = "area name if use" })" class="home">Logout </a></li>

 }
 else
 {
   <li> <a href="@Url.Action("Login","Account")" class="home">Login </a></li>

 }
```